# Is there a way to have required modules on local machine rather than to get them online

Tags: go

I work in a closed environment in which machines do not have access to internet. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to load the dependency modules for development with Go. One way I am thinking is to get the package files, if there is any. However, I couldn't find any such file for the dependencies I am using.

Comment: In the Go modules wiki: [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)

Comment: What about pointing GOPROXY at a local module cache?

Comment: Thanks, BenjaminW and JimB, for the hints. It looks like GOPROXY is something I can try. I'll do more experiments with it and see if it resolves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you could do:

1. You can use `replace` directives in your `go.mod` file to redirect packages to local directories where you have copies of the dependency packages.
2. You can use `go mod vendor` (see [docs](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-vendor)) to "vendor" dependency packages locally.
3. You can use a local proxy and set the `GOPROXY` env var.